# Can you explain how this NoAlphanumeric JS code works?

Tags: javascript

I found a javascript code on the web (called NoAlphanumeric JS):

```
_=[]|[];$=_++;__=(_<<_);___=(_<<_)+_;____=__+__;_____=__+___;$$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}[$]+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[___]+(($==$)+"")[$]+(($==$)+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[__]+({}+"")[_____]+(($==$)+"")[$]+({}+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[_];$$$=(($!=$)+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[__]+(($==$)+"")[___]+(($==$)+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[$];$_$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[__]+({}+"")[__+_____]+({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}[$]+"")[__]+(($==$)+"")[___]; ($)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

This code will open an "alert" and print "cool code"...

Can someone explain how this code works?

Comment: You can go through it statement by statement and see the result. For examples `[]|[]` results in `0`, hence `_++` gives `1`. In general, the idea is to extract single characters from string representations of internal objects. For example, `($==$)+""` results in the string `"true"`.

Comment: @downvoters, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: Wow, this is now a daily question.

Comment: If you wonder why specific operations yield the respective results, I can only suggest to look up the operation in the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm) and see how the data types are converted.

Comment: @FelixKing Thanks. Now I understand the idea behind this kind of code

Answer (score 4):

Here goes!

#### Adding line breaks

... and some comments

```
// Variable declarations
_=[]|[];
$=_++;
__=(_<<_);
___=(_<<_)+_;
____=__+__;
_____=__+___;

// Variable declarations that "do stuff"
$$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}[$]+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[___]+(($==$)+"")[$]+(($==$)+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[__]+({}+"")[_____]+(($==$)+"")[$]+({}+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[_];
$$$=(($!=$)+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[__]+(($==$)+"")[___]+(($==$)+"")[_]+(($==$)+"")[$];
$_$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}+"")[_]+(($!=$)+"")[__]+({}+"")[__+_____]+({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[_]+({}[$]+"")[__]+(($==$)+"")[___];

// Final function call
($)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

#### Expanding declarations 1

```
// Variable declarations
// _=[]|[];  ->  replace `_` with 0
$=0;          //  (actually, 1)
__=(1<<1);    // 2
___=(1<<1)+1; // 3
____=2+2;     // 4
_____=2+3;    // 5

// Variable declarations that "do stuff"
$$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[1]+({}[0]+"")[1]+((0!=0)+"")[___]+((0==0)+"")[0]+((0==0)+"")[1]+((0==0)+"")[__]+({}+"")[_____]+((0==0)+"")[0]+({}+"")[1]+((0==0)+"")[1];
$$$=((0!=0)+"")[1]+((0!=0)+"")[__]+((0==0)+"")[___]+((0==0)+"")[1]+((0==0)+"")[0];
$_$=({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[1]+({}+"")[1]+((0!=0)+"")[__]+({}+"")[__+_____]+({}+"")[_____]+({}+"")[1]+({}[0]+"")[__]+((0==0)+"")[___];

// Final function call
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

#### Expanding declarations 2

More expansions of variables, and let's evaluate those `0==0` and `0!=0`s.

```
// Variable declarations that "do stuff"
$$=({}+"")[5]+({}+"")[1]+({}[0]+"")[1]+((false)+"")[3]+((true)+"")[0]+((true)+"")[1]+((true)+"")[2]+({}+"")[5]+((true)+"")[0]+({}+"")[1]+((true)+"")[1];
$$$=((false)+"")[1]+((false)+"")[2]+((true)+"")[3]+((true)+"")[1]+((true)+"")[0];
$_$=({}+"")[5]+({}+"")[1]+({}+"")[1]+((false)+"")[2]+({}+"")[2+5]+({}+"")[5]+({}+"")[1]+({}[0]+"")[2]+((true)+"")[3];

// Final function call
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

#### String building

`(true)+""` is equal to `"true"`, and `(false)+""` is equal to `"false"`. Also, `{}+""` becomes `"[object Object]"`, and `{}[0]+""` becomes `"undefined"`:

```
// Variable declarations that "do stuff"
$$=("[object Object]")[5]+("[object Object]")[1]+("undefined")[1]+("false")[3]+("true")[0]+("true")[1]+("true")[2]+("[object Object]")[5]+("true")[0]+("[object Object]")[1]+("true")[1];
$$$=("false")[1]+("false")[2]+("true")[3]+("true")[1]+("true")[0];
$_$=("[object Object]")[5]+("[object Object]")[1]+("[object Object]")[1]+("false")[2]+("[object Object]")[2+5]+("[object Object]")[5]+("[object Object]")[1]+("undefined")[2]+("true")[3];

// Final function call
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

And, indexing (`[0]` and `[1]` etc) into these strings:

```
$$="c"+"o"+"n"+"s"+"t"+"r"+"u"+"c"+"t"+"o"+"r";
$$$="a"+"l"+"e"+"r"+"t";
$_$="c"+"o"+"o"+"l"+" "+"c"+"o"+"d"+"e";

// Final function call
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

And combining:

```
$$="constructor";
$$$="alert";
$_$="cool code";

// Final function call
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

#### Execution

Now it gets a little more tricky.

```
(0)[$$][$$]($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

`(0)["constructor"]["constructor"]` is the same as `(0).constructor.constructor` and yields the `Function` constructor (the constructor of the constructor of `Number`):

```
(Function)($$$+"('"+$_$+"')")()
```

Expanding the variables:

```
(Function)("alert"+"('"+"cool code"+"')")()
```

and contracting:

```
(Function)("alert('cool code')")()
```

Casting that string to a `Function` object has the effect of creating a function that'll `eval` that code, so, we end up with:

```
(function() { alert('cool code') {})()
```

with the `()` executing the function.

#### Bootnote

I accept Paypal.

Comment: I'd got most of that except was a bit hazy on that execution step. In particular is that really casting the string to a function? Its just occured to me (after my above edit) that it is more probably effectively calling the constructor to create a new Fucntion based on the string passed to it. Certainly the syntax there is not as you have quoted since the Function constructor doesn't have brackets around it, it is followed immediately by the () which makes it much more method call like. Sadly I've never dug much into the core of JS to look at how the built in stuff like this works. :)

Comment: @Chris: (a) `In particular is that really casting the string to a function? Its just occured to me (after my above edit) that it is more probably effectively calling the constructor to create a new Fucntion based on the string passed to it` What's the difference between the two? (b) `Certainly the syntax there is not as you have quoted since the Function constructor doesn't have brackets around it, it is followed immediately by the () which makes it much more method call like` Not relevant. Try `(alert)('lol')`.

Comment: Ah, cool. Well, in my defence I did say I hadn't got into a lot of the nuts and bolts of it. :) Thinking about it I realise that my comment on the brackets in alert was silly since functions are just object. On the matter of casting vs calling the constructor method I would have said that they were different in other languages but javascript is a lot more loose with objects than things like C# so I am prepared to accept there is no difference if that is what you are telling me. Its just that the syntax looked like method calling rather than casting (does that even exist in JS actually?).

Comment: And I just remembered to give you the +1 I forgot to on first looking at your answer. :)

Comment: @JohnJohnGa Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the code utilizes Javascript error and type outputs to concoct various characters. For instance, an out put of "NaN" will yield the characters "N" and "a", and you can select them as you would any character string in Javascript -- The equivalent of v[0] selecting "N" and v[1] selecting "a".

This is, at best, an elementary explanation, but given some of the comments on this question, my guess is that there is a far more comprehensive answer somewhere else on Stack.

Answer (score 2):

Start breaking it down yourself in console...

```
_=[]|[];  // ===  _=0
$=_++;    // ===  $=0, _=1
__=(_<<_) // === __=2
```

...etc.  Just break it apart on the semi-colons and start testing :)  Ask any *specific* questions you want, like "why does `[]|[] === 0`?"

After that, I'm assuming this takes advantage of JS error messages, vars, e.g. using "undefined", "NaN", "true", "false" you can do anything using the letters in just those...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to try to translate for you because asw @LightnessRacesinOrbit said its a big job. What I would suggest is to firstly split it into multiple lines by splitting on semi-colons and then perhaps start renaming the variables into something a little more easy to distinguish between.

This is what's called obfuscated code and is designed to be as unintelligible as possible. Using different variables such as `_`, `__`, `___`, etc. just makes it hard to keep in mind what each holds. Split it up and rename it and if necessary just stick an alert in between every statement to see what the most recent operation has done (or better yet run it in a debugger, etc.) will then let you see how it works.

**Edit**:

Actually its not as bad as I thought...

It sets up the following constants initially with some simple mathsy stuff once its got the 0 from []|[]. I assume it does these more complicatedly to add to the obfuscation...

```
_ = 1
$ = 0
__ = 2
___ = 3
____ = 4
_____ = 5
```

It then uses the following to get a string/character array to get some characters out of:

```
({}+"") - [object Object]
({}[$]+"") undefined
(($!=$)+"") false
(($==$)+"") true
```

The last things are then just concatenating those strings to get:

```
$$ - constructor
$$$ - alert
$_$ - cool code
```

The last line then uses some magic I'm not entirely clear on to then call the alert function... I think it possibly rewrites the constructor on an object or something like that. That is the only bit I'm a bit hazy on...

**Final Edit:**

I've worked out the magic.

`($)['constructor']['constructor']` seems to be Function() and if you call it with a string argument it seems to create an anonymous method based on that string. The final brackets then call that anonymous member that if you've followed up to here you will know calls the alert.